# How to extract only "Out of Office" time in Outlook 365 Calendar? And share among multiple users?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I am trying to investigate a solution for sharing planned vacation/OOO time with multiple users in an organization. I see Outlook has a few features that come close, but do not quite do what I want. I'm hoping someone knows how to configure the available features to get the end result I have in mind. Here are my requirements:

- Everyone puts their vacation/out of office time on their own calendar, as "Out of Office" time
- A group calendar (e.g. "Team Vacation Calendar") is then created and shared to automatically show only the "Out of Office" time of several users. Non-"Out of Office" would never show on this calendar
- When an individual updates/add/removes "Out of Office" items on their calendar, "Team Vacation Calendar" is kept in sync with that.
- People's individual calendars can be added/removed from "Team Vacation Calendar" at any time

The closest I have come to this is creating a custom view of several people's calendars overlayed on top of each other, with a filter to only show Out of Office time. The problem with this is your view settings persist across calendars, so if you then navigate back to your individual calendar, only your Out of Office time shows. And if you reset your view on the overlayed calendar, suddenly you are looking at ALL of everyone's appointments overlayed on top of each other. And lastly, I want the definition of the calendar to be static, i.e., I want it to be a single calendar called "Team Vacation Calendar" and not several calendars overlayed. That will be too difficult to manage having the calendar used by several people on the team. They will inevitably change the overlay structure and not understand why it looks different for them.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Based on my experience, I’m afraid that we cannot only share “Out of Office” items and cannot set custom view to one calendar folder. One workaround I figured out may be to create a shared calendar and let everyone to manually update their vacation on this calendar. Or a shared mailbox, If users want to add OOF events, they can always invite the shared mailbox.

Comment: @Perry, that last comment could work actually. Let me see if I understand this right - create a shared "mailbox" (which to me just sounds like additional outlook account everyone shares) for vacation. Then people create appointments on their calendar for vacation and invite the "vacation" account. Then those events will all show on the "vacation" account's calendar, which everyone can see.

Comment: Yes, an extra account whose calendar is shared to everyone.